# VANET simulation using NS3 and SUMO == error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

Tags: python, osmdroid, sumo, ns-3

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 Vbox and SUMO Version v1_4_0+0288-8b0d3cd and NS3-dev to simulate VANET. During the generation of the SUMO Scenario (road map) in OSM web Wizard I get this error:

```
amin@amin-VirtualBox:~/sumo/tools$ python osmWebWizard.py 
Building scenario in '/home/amin/sumo/tools/2020-01-02-11-20-03'
Downloading map data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "osmWebWizard.py", line 442, in build
    builder.build()
  File "osmWebWizard.py", line 190, in build
    ["-b", ",".join(map(str, self.data["coords"])), "-p", self.prefix, "-d", self.tmp])
  File "/home/amin/sumo/tools/osmGet.py", line 116, in get
    (north, south, west, east), options.prefix + "_bbox.osm.xml")
  File "/home/amin/sumo/tools/osmGet.py", line 47, in readCompressed
    </osm-script>""" % query)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1073, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1113, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1069, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 907, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 869, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1286, in connect
    HTTPConnection.connect(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 846, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

Recovering
Recovering
Recovering
Recovering
```

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: There is no specific code till now. I'm just trying to generate the road map using OSM web wizard.
After installing SUMO i use the commends:
$] cd sumo/tools
$] python osmWebWizard.py
After this the osm web wizard opened in the web browser, I Select the cars, buses, motorcycles, etc. and generate the scenario, now, during the generation of the scenario i get the error above.